# Amazon Athena supported SQL Query to Count rows of few Tables

Tags: sql, database, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

In a Database with 10 Tables, I want to query to count row (Count(*)) of tables T2,T3,T4,T5,T7, based on Date range. Like no. of record last loaded, loaded between a date range, and get out put as. Eg:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could `UNION` the results of several queries, eg:

```sql
SELECT 'T2' as TableName, COUNT(*), MAX(DATE) FROM t2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'T3' as TableName, COUNT(*), MAX(DATE) FROM t3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'T4' as TableName, COUNT(*), MAX(DATE) FROM t4
UNION ALL
SELECT 'T5' as TableName, COUNT(*), MAX(DATE) FROM t5
UNION ALL
SELECT 'T7' as TableName, COUNT(*), MAX(DATE) FROM t7
```